# Why my objects getting "flipped" when the viewport is set to shaded or rendered?

Tags: rendering, shaders, sverchok

I'm trying to [follow this yt tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FELFjIw-0d8&t=215s) which should produce a flower using Sverchok.

The problem occurs when I'm judging my result in the rendered view. If I'm rotating the viewport the leaves seem to "flip". Looks like I disorder of the visualizing of the leaves... but honestly, I have no idea what causes this.

I think thousand of words can not describe what a few seconds video can, so please have a look: https://youtu.be/gqnynFoe68E

[image]

The object rotated in viewport:

[image]

The issue only happens when the shading is set to rendered or shaded, no issue in sold view though.

Result by using just the distance node:

[image]

A bit rotated:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you tweak the value of the Greater Than node just a tiny bit? Problem could be that the Distance is almost exactly 3.660 but due to floating point calculations it very slightly varies as you rotate. The Greater Than gives a hard edge cutoff between 0 and 1, losing the gradient you have set up in the color ramp node.

Comment: @RichSedman: happens the same. I add the greater than node to it to make it clearer. With the colorramp the difference wasn't that clear. I update my answer without "greater than" node

Comment: In that case, rotating just the view shouldn’t be affecting the Location coordinate at all - unless the mesh is being dynamically altered based on the viewport. I must admit to not really knowing much about Sverchok.

Comment: @RichSedman : nothing was animated to that point. That’s why I wondered…

Comment: Does it happen the same if you use another version of blender? maybe 3.0 is still too buggy. It does not seem a Sverchok bug

Comment: I didn‘t try. After updating all nodes and replugging the output nodes it worked again. But it was weird ‍♂️